# Переключение блоков на другие блоки когда мишка внизу блока

Tags: javascript, jquery, веб-программирование, вёрстка

Доброе время суток !!!э html которая состоит с 4 блоков как сделать что когда мышка подходит к низу блока сразу бросало на следующий нижний блок, а когда верх то на верхний блок, я знаю как сделать с помощью якорей а при нажатии   нет

Comment: "как сделать..." - через события MouseEvent.